# Crystal Reports; Chart Expert: creating a chart with two date ranges in X axis

Tags: sql, charts, crystal-reports

Currently struggling to acheive what I want with charts in Crystal Reports.

I've got parameters for a start and end date, so the chart would be dynamic and 
in the X Axis, I want to be able to specify two dates...  one being **Received** and the other being **Completed**.

So we would see in the Chart Expert a Bar Chart that has

```
"On Change of" 
    with the Recieved date (for each month) and Completed date (for each month)

"Show Value(s):"
    DistinctCount(ItemsToCount)
```

The point of this chart is to show a comparison month to month of how many ItemsToCount are being **Received** and being **Completed** in any given month.

I think the problem I am facing is that there are times when the **Received** Date and **Completed** Date within the same month and may be causing problems.  Or that possibly that the ItemToCount has been **received** in the last month but not yet been **completed**...

Before asking this, I created a pretty static chart that had logic to say,

```
if the month(received)=1 THEN ItemsToCount ELSE {@Null}
```

and I had 12 of those formulas plus another 12 for the **completed** months.

But now the end user is asking for a much larger time period...  so I don't think the static approach will work for this chart!

Any help is greatly appreciated.  If there are any SQL tricks to accomodate the chart expert, I am certainly willing to try it... not above using subreports ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best solution is to alter your incoming SQL to closely match the data you want to appear in the chart. (You have more flexibility/power in altering the SQL as opposed to trying to shoehorn the Crystal Charting). So if you haven't already, switch your report datasource to use a SQL Command and use a command similar to the following:

```
select 
  ISNULL(tbl1.MNTH, tbl2.MNTH) as RptMonth, 
  ISNULL(tbl1.CNT,0) as ReceivedCount, 
  ISNULL(tbl2.CNT,0) as CompletedCount 
from 
  (select dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, R.RCV_DT),0) as MNTH, COUNT(*) as CNT 
     from T_YOUR_SOURCE_TABLE  R
     GROUP BY dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, R.RCV_DT),0) 
  ) tbl1
  FULL OUTER JOIN 
  (select dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, R.INV_DT),0) as MNTH, COUNT(*) as CNT
     from T_YOUR_SOURCE_TABLE  R
     GROUP BY dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, R.INV_DT),0) ) tbl2
  on tbl1.MNTH = tbl2.MNTH
where ISNULL(tbl1.MNTH, tbl2.MNTH) between '{CrystalStartDateParam}' and '{CrystalEndDateParam}'   
order by tbl1.MNTH
```

This way you are pulling data into the report in a format that looks like this:

```
RptMonth                ReceivedCount CompletedCount
2005-01-01 00:00:00.000 1465    1269
2005-02-01 00:00:00.000 1264    1163
2005-03-01 00:00:00.000 1466    1561
2005-04-01 00:00:00.000 1505    1504
2005-05-01 00:00:00.000 1329    1416
2005-06-01 00:00:00.000 1540    1529
2005-07-01 00:00:00.000 1263    1216
2005-08-01 00:00:00.000 1249    1316
2005-09-01 00:00:00.000 1520    1460
2005-10-01 00:00:00.000 1448    1240
2005-11-01 00:00:00.000 1321    1239
2005-12-01 00:00:00.000 1421    1302
```

Which then makes the charting in Crystal much easier, and of course can then handle the variable start/end dates.

Comment: Im going to give that a go.  Thanks for your quick response!

Comment: Man that is great.   I did not consider using the ISNULL function AT ALL and also the FULL OUTER JOIN.   I think my mistake before was that I had a join for the start and end dates to say either the received date or the completed date were within the daterange... it wasn't specific enough which is where doing the full on SQL command really shines.  Thanks so much @Douglas !